# How to limit onScroll() effects to one method call per touch event

Tags: android

This is one of my first Android projects, so bear with me a bit. I'm having trouble limiting the onScroll() method to one iteration, for lack of a better word. The scenario that is occurring is that when I do a scroll where distanceX is, say 130, index is being incremented by 4, instead of the intended 1. I'm trying to find a way to make the index increase by 1 per swipe event, no matter how large distanceX is. I did and if-else-if construct all the way up to 240, incrementing by 40, but that didn't seem to work either.

Here is the relevant code- I cut out all the other implemented methods of GestureDetector.OnGestureListener.

```
public class QuoteActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements
    GestureDetector.OnGestureListener,GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener{

private GestureDetectorCompat detect;
private TextView textQuote;
private String[] quotes;
private int index = 0;


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.quote_main);

    textQuote = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_quote);
    quotes = getResources().getStringArray(ProcessQuote.getArray());
    textQuote.setText(quotes[index]);

    detect = new GestureDetectorCompat(this,this);
    detect.setOnDoubleTapListener(this);
}


@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    detect.onTouchEvent(event);
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}



public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
    if(distanceX > 40 && index < quotes.length-1){
        index++;
        textQuote.setText(quotes[index]);
    }else if(distanceX < -40 && index > 0) {
        index--;
        textQuote.setText(quotes[index]);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This solution appears to address your problem and could be a duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13189620/gesturedetector-onscroll-issue-executed-3-times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store your scroll offsets:
`float scrollstartX1, scrollStartY1;`

Then only run the action after the scroll evaluation, but only if the co-ordinates are different.

```
public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
  if (scrollstartX1 != e1.getX() || scrollStartY1 != e1.getY()) {
    scrollstartX1 = e1.getX();
    scrollStartY1 = e1.getY();
    //Code here should only execute once per scroll
  }
}
```

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13189620/gesturedetector-onscroll-issue-executed-3-times)

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thanks for the code and link, it made it work and increased my understanding as well.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you want onFling() rather than onScroll()...

```
@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent event1, MotionEvent event2, 
        float velocityX, float velocityY) {
    Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onFling: " + event1.toString()+event2.toString());
    return true;
}
```